# Avoid self closing tags in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying below code to serialize an object. The problem is if some elements are null then they have self closing tags like below:

`<City/>` which I want to be like this `<City> </City>`. Any thoughts?

```
private string GetXMLFromObject(object o)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);
    XmlSerializerNamespaces names = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    names.Add("", "");
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(writer, o, names);
    ms.Flush();
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return xml;
}
```

Comment: Like `<City> </City>` or `<City></City>`? Also, according to the XML specs an element with self-closing tags is semantically equivalent to one that immediately closes, so *why* do you want this?

Comment: I need to pass the XML to a WCF service which does not recognize this,

Comment: You need to say why self-closing tags are a problem. There's something wrong with your design if you can't handle well-formed XML downstream.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to validity, both `<City/>` and  `<City> </City>` are valid and will be processed correctly by any XML Parser.

If you still want to force it, do as follows. What you are looking for is the `WriteFullEndElement()` method. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writefullendelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("City");
writer.WriteString(inputCity);
writer.WriteFullEndElement();
```

This will force it to serialize `City` as `<City></City>` when `inputCity` is empty.